# Sphinxsearch with the Left Join and And Or where Condition

Tags: sql, sphinx

## store

id
name

## brand

id
name

## brand_store

store_id
brand_id

## product

id
name
description
brand_id
store_id

Now i want to execute Query

```
select p.* from product p
LEFT join brand_store bs ON bs.brand_id=p.brand_id
where
p.id NOT IN (1,5,4)
AND p.brand_id in (1487,457,5725)
and (bs.store_id = 1 OR p.store_id =1)
```

can one suggest what should be the sql_query in sphinx.conf and how can set filter to this ?

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is the `sql_query` should :-

**SELECT** all the columns you may need to filter on (from WHERE of original), or retrieve, order, group by etc. basically all the data that needs entering into the index.

**JOIN** all the tables needed to get those columns

generally avoid a **WHERE** - as filtering will be done in Sphinx, but can exclude rows you KNOW will never need matching (eg inactive rows)

generally avoid a **GROUP BY** - again grouping is done in Sphinx

generally avoid a **ORDER BY** - results are reordered anyway, the sql_query is just used to build the index.

use `sql_attr*` directives to define which of the columns become attributes, fields or both.

Comment: Hello barry, Thanks for reply,
I have tried as 
`sql_query  = \
  SELECT p.id, p.name, p.description, p.weight,p.brand_id,p.store_id,bs.store_id, dimension \
  FROM product p\
                LEFT JOIN brand__store bs ON p.brand_id = bs.brand_id \
sql_attr_uint  = brand_id
sql_attr_uint  = store_id
`
Please suggest...

Comment: Suggest what, please?

Comment: what i need to do , to satisfy Query `select p.* from product p
LEFT join brand_store bs ON bs.brand_id=p.brand_id
where
p.id NOT IN (1,5,4)
AND p.brand_id in (1487,457,5725)
and (bs.store_id = 1 OR p.store_id =1) `

PHP Code and Conf  configuration changes

Comment: yes i tried with adding 
`sql_query  = \
  SELECT p.id, name,sku,p.brand_id,p.store_id,created_at \
  FROM product p\
                LEFT JOIN brand__store bs ON p.brand_id = bs.brand_id \`

In conf file 

`$this->sphinx = new sfSphinxClient($options);
    $this->sphinx->ResetFilters();
    $this->sphinx->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ANY);
$res = $this->sphinx->Query($this->query,'test');`